# Is there any way to save your progress in the Endurance Races?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I've reached the final series in GT5, the Endurance Series, which features races that range from 4 hours to 24 hours in length.  As I do not have 24 hours of free time for gaming, nor do I relish the thought of a power outage causing me to lose 22 hours of racing, I was wondering if there is any way to save your progress in these races.

I've started a couple of them and there does not appear to be any relevant options on the pause menu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go into the pit. There will be a "suspend" option. Then you can freely exit the game via the PS button.
**BUT** you cannot do any other activities until you are finished with the endurance race, which GT5 will prompt you about next time you start up the game.